# Can't get insertion sort from 'The introdaction to algorithms 2nd edition'

Tags: algorithm, insertion

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1   for j <- 2 to length[A]
2       do key <- A[j]
3          //Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1 □ j - 1].
4          i <- j - 1
5          while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6           do A[i+1] <- A[i]
7              i <- i -1
8          A[i + 1] <- key
```

In line 1 we start from the second element of an array (it's how I understand the translation of pseudocode to actual code on any prog lang) but what if we were given a collection of just one element? Or was that case just excluded from consideration?
(I'm not studying in uni just by myself so I can't get help from a prof, sorry if the question is basic)

Comment: How would you sort a collection of one element? What operations would you need to do to transition from an unsorted 1-e collection to a sorted one?

Comment: I wouldn't, given the collection of 1 element  we just return it as is because it is already sorted, but in the book, it is not specified so I thought I missing something :/

Comment: The code modifies its argument A and for a one-element collection it does nothing, which is the right thing to do.

Comment: yet one small question
why here is written A[1..j − 1]
why j - 1, in the pseudocode sequence start with 1 so why do we need to extract 1 from the length?

Comment: Each step of the outer loop takes A[j] and finds the right spot for it. So at the beginning of step x, A is already sorted up to x-1.